# javascript extraction of spaces between two markers

Tags: javascript, regex

I,
I try to select all spaces (space & tabs) between two markers.
My regexp is :

```
/(?<=start)(\s+)(?=end)/gi
```

A sample string is :

```
this is a start marker with some words and end marker.
```

Where is the mistake ?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that it will only select white space between your two markers when the characters between those two markers are *exclusively* white space.

See the following [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iOoRUp/1/).

There may be a more clever way of accomplishing what you need but the simplest way that comes to my mind is to first select all the text between the start and end markers because it is very easy to do that:

```
/(?<=start)[\s\S]*(?=end)/
```

where

```
[\s\S]* matches 0 or more characters (white or non-white space characters, including the newline).
```

Then depending on what you want to do, you process the Group 0 string accordingly. If you are interested knowing how many white space characters there are, for example, then the following code snippet would do the trick:

```js
let text = 'this is a start marker with some words and end marker.';
let regexp = /(?<=start)[\s\S]*(?=end)/;
match = text.match(regexp); // extract text between markers
let s = match[0]; // this is extracted text
regexp = /\s/g;
let matches = s.matchAll(regexp); // match all single white space chatacters
matches = Array.from(matches);
console.log(matches.length);
```

You have to first extract both the white space and non-white space characters that exist between the markers and then match all white space characters.

If instead you want to replace the white space characters with the empty string (i.e. get rid of them), then the following snippet would accomplish this:

```js
let text = 'this is a start marker with some words and end marker.';
let regexp = /(?<=start)[\s\S]*(?=end)/; // extract text between markers
function replacer(match)
{
    return match.replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
text = text.replace(regexp, replacer);
console.log(text);
```

Again, first all of the text between the start and end markers is selected and from that text the white space is replaced.

Comment: Ok, this explain me better what is happening. And I did'nt know the synthax "text = text.replace(regexp, replacer);". Thanks.